# r.reclass for NDVI in QGIS gives no output

Tags: raster, ndvi

I have a raster layer with NDVI values. I want to reclassify the raster to five classes. The project and the layer are in EPSG 32633.

When I use `r.reclass` in QGIS, there is no output.

What is the error?

[image]

Comment: I get an error when using >< signs. Try 0.93 thru 999 = 5

Comment: I have also tried this way but the problem is the same again.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `Reclassify by table` tool which does the same as `r.class` tool. However, it is more manageable as it gives you min, max, and value in an organized way to avoid any incorrect syntax when you write it as a text.

1. Select the input raster layer

[image]

2. Select the table and write the minimum, maximum, and new value. The default is min < value <= max

[image]

You can change the data type to `int16` or any desired output data type.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]